Inaccurate estimates for geospatial types
This is my first dabble with Postgres and geospatial.
Looking at a slow query which includes ST_Intersects(a.geography, b.geography). The optimiser estimates are 2500x out.
https://explain.dalibo.com/plan/a62aed5287a6a6g8
Before I turn to pg_hint_plan to force a better plan, are there any other options for improving geospatial column statistics? Are inaccurate statistics a recurring issue in geospatial queries?

I certainly can't reproduce that, but without seeing the rest of the plan maybe I shouldn't expect to be able to reproduce it.

@jjanes added plan. I think the problem is solved but please answer if you have any ideas, otherwise I'll self-answer next week.

The geometries here turned out to be buildings within a country scale. Geospatial indexes are inefficient with large, complex geometries.

Point-in-polygon and other spatial operations are normally faster for indexed subdivided datasets. Since the bounding boxes for the parts usually cover a smaller area than the original geometry bbox, index queries produce fewer "hit" cases. The "hit" cases are faster because the spatial operations executed by the index recheck process fewer points. link

Using ST_Subdive to split the country scale geometries was effective.
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW IF NOT EXISTS dt_citus.perimeter_divided
AS
    SELECT
        cityobject_id
        , ST_Subdivide(geometry) AS geometry
    FROM
        io.perimeter;

CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS perimeter_divided_geometry
ON  dt_citus.perimeter_divided USING gist (geometry);

Estimates are now 10x out, much improved. Haven't yet experimented with varying the max_vertices parameter, which defaults to 256.
